# Ubuntu 15.04 Server - How to stop X from starting at boot

Tags: boot, xorg, 15.04

I'm new to Ubuntu.  Just setup a system with 15.04 Server.
I installed X because I sometimes want to use it but it's automatically starting at boot.
How do I disable this?
I still want startx to work (when I need it).

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 2):

Edit your /etc/default/grub

```
sudo nano /etc/default/grub
```

Find out this line -

```
GRUB_CMDLINE_LINUX_DEFAULT="quiet splash"
```

Change it to -

```
GRUB_CMDLINE_LINUX_DEFAULT="text"
```

Update Grub -

```
sudo update-grub
```

For systems that use systemd
This is an additional step for systemd releases, eg: Ubuntu 15.04

You need to tell systemd to not load the graphical login manager:

```
sudo systemctl enable multi-user.target --force
sudo systemctl set-default multi-user.target
```

You can still use X by typing `startx` after you logged in

Comment: Thanks!  My grub file has: GRUB_CMDLINE_LINUX_DEFAULT="" and 
GRUB_CMDLINE_LINUX=""     Should I still add "text" to the statement above?   Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

Edit your `/etc/default/grub`

```
sudo nano /etc/default/grub
```

Find this line -

```
GRUB_CMDLINE_LINUX_DEFAULT="quiet splash"
```

Change it to -

```
GRUB_CMDLINE_LINUX_DEFAULT="text"
```

Update Grub -

```
sudo update-grub
```

This is the first answer after days of searching that has WORKED!
System is i386, Linux Mint 17.1, Mate DM,

Comment: This by itself only shows the startup progress as text, but does not prevent X from starting - the login manager (lightdm or gdm) will start X too.