# How to install LXDE and keep default login

Tags: 16.04, server, lxde, ham-radio

I would like to install LXDE on my router, but whenever I do it using `sudo apt-get install lxde` it replaces the default login screen with the LXDE login screen, I would like to install LXDE, BUT keep the command line as the default login.

In my chromebook I have a chroot and to start LXDE on it using `startlxde` and I want to able to do the same on my server, since I'm working on setting up a SDR based HAM radio station that runs on the server.

Comment: I am not familiar with what the `startlxde` script probably is.  You might want to look on your chromebook with maybe a `cat $(which startlxde)` and see the contents of it.  For booting to the Command Line log in after you install lxde see https://askubuntu.com/a/859637/231142

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I installed it via `lxde-core` for the core desktop and `openbox` for the x server and misc. utilities