# How to edit GRUB after POST for text only console mode?

Tags: boot, command-line, grub2, grubrescue, rescue-mode

How do I edit the `GRUB` boot sequence from:

`linux /boot/vmlinuz... quiet splash`

so that it boots to the console?  I've tried removing "quiet" and "splash", as well as adding "text".  I can also boot to rescue [mode](https://askubuntu.com/q/1022989/45156), or edit the boot sequence.

Else booting hangs at the splash screen.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to start Ubuntu in Console mode](https://askubuntu.com/questions/859630/how-to-start-ubuntu-in-console-mode)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

To start without the display manager edit the file `/boot/grub/grub.cfg`. Look for the default menuentry (usually the first line beginning with `menuentry 'Ubuntu'` and some lines later append `3` to the line starting your kernel:

```
linux   /boot/vmlinuz-4.13.0-38-generic.efi.signed root=UUID=3fbf407e-3505-42c7-82a7-7aceef817bcc ro 3
```

To start the display manager later on do

```
sudo init 5
```

Comment: see:  https://askubuntu.com/a/859637/45156  will those work?  why not?  it's like there are 99 ways to configure this.  I tried systemctl from rescue system, but no go.