# How do I install Ubuntu without the GUI?

Tags: command-line, system-installation

I would like to install Ubuntu without the GUI so that it's all command/text based?

Comment: You can boot a GUI distribution in console mode to live in the CLI environment: https://askubuntu.com/questions/859630/how-to-start-ubuntu-in-console-mode/859637#859637

Answer (score 16):

### Ubuntu Server

Ubuntu Server is sometimes called Ubuntu Live Server because during a period of time there were two versions with different installers. The Ubuntu Server iso files are officially released by Canonical, the company that supports Ubuntu. Ubuntu Server is FOSS, and there is optional paid, professional support, and also ESM.

- The main purpose of Ubuntu Server is to be installed as a server, which is obvious from the name.
- You can also **use the Ubuntu Server iso file to create a simple and light-weight installed system with a command line interface**: Avoid installing the typical server program packages (optional during the installation).

Until and including version 20.04 LTS there is (was) also the Ubuntu `mini.iso` that could install a minimal command-line system.

#### Links:

Download Ubuntu Server via this official link with several alternatives,

https://ubuntu.com/download

or the following link with the server files alongside the desktop files of Ubuntu (mainly for PC with Intel/AMD processors).

https://releases.ubuntu.com/

Answer (score 4):

Generally this is done with:

- The [mini ISO](https://help.ubuntu.com/community/Installation/MinimalCD) (scroll down for ISO files), which fits even on CDs but which requires an Internet connection which will download hundreds of megabytes or several gigabytes of data while installing. Make sure, when the software selection screen comes up, to not choose any desktops.
- The [Ubuntu Server ISO](https://www.ubuntu.com/download/server), which needs a DVD or a 1 GB USB drive and doesn't require an Internet connection while installing.

Comment: *"download hundreds of megabytes or several gigabytes"* this is confusing to me.

Answer (score 0):

### GRUB Boot Option

During your computer boot, it'll list its hardware. That's when you should repeatedly press `F8` until you see the advanced GRUB boot options. One of the options will give you access to the command line.

### Installation Option

You can choose to use an Ubuntu network installer. For example, you can [download the network installer for Ubuntu 18.04.5](https://cdimage.ubuntu.com/netboot/18.04/?_ga=2.29342012.1832263245.1630057400-1708240238.1630057400) so you can install Ubuntu with no GUI but all the needed features for normal usage, accessible from the command line. You could also [download the manual installer for Ubuntu server](https://ubuntu.com/download/server). Both the options require a physical installation medium to be connected to the target device.

Answer (score -2):

You can try @Chai T. Rex or if you have already installed Ubuntu OS then you can unistall all your Desktop Environments. 
Eg if you have gnome desktop environment then you can do

```
sudo apt remove gnome gnome-extras
```

And then

```
sudo apt autoremove

sudo apt autoclean
```

Comment: nea, because then ubuntu is already installed