# How do I rescue my Ubuntu server from the sever ISO ubuntu-18.04.1-live-server-amd64.ISO?

Tags: server, 18.04

Before the **18.04** version, I used to just boot from the server ISO and access the "rescue from a broken system" option right from the menu. It appears that the rescue options were removed from the new ISOs. Did something change that i need to be aware of?  Do i Need to use an older ISO to get the "Rescue from a Broken System"  menu option?   Why is this option removed? is there a better option?

Answer (score 1):

for the record, the *20.04* server live install iso just does't have it. don't let people mislead you if you run into that.

Answer (score 0):

Boot your live system and right after the bios POST press shift or esc (I read that somewhere and just alternated so I don't know which or maybe both work).  Then you can choose the "advanced" options and rescue mode is one of them, after which you can choose "root" to drop to a  root shell.

Comment: Usually the correct key to press is Shift for BIOS and Esc for UEFI. For more information see [Boot into recovery mode](https://askubuntu.com/questions/859630/how-to-start-ubuntu-in-console-mode/859640#859640).