# After booting in console mode I can't go back to automatic GUI mode

Tags: boot, grub2, xorg

So because I had problems with my XOrg-Server I wanted to boot into console mode and followed the steps listed [here](https://askubuntu.com/a/859637)

However when I followed the undo step it didn't work. Now whenever I boot my laptop I have to login via console and manually type "startx" to get into my GUI.

```
systemctl get-default
```

returns this value:

```
graphical.target
```

This is really annoying and I hope someone can help me out here.

Comment: Undo the changes you made to `/etc/default/grub` and run `update-grub` again.

Comment: @danzel Didn't help unfortunately. Everything is back to as it was before I made the changes and still I boot into tty1. Double checked everything.