# Ctrl-Alt-F1 Unavailable after removing python3

Tags: system, software-uninstall

I recently removed [python3](https://packages.ubuntu.com/bionic/python3) from my Ubuntu 18.04 system, and the next time I tried to logon I was greeted with a failed to start session error when entering my credentials. Unfortunately, <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>-<kbd>Alt</kbd>-<kbd>F1</kbd> does not open a TTY for me.   Trying <kbd>Ctrl</kbd><kbd>Alt</kbd>-<kbd>F2</kbd> etc. also does nothing.

I am OK with re-installing Ubuntu, but unsure if this is necessary at this time.

Comment: Please try Ctrl-Alt-F2 Ctrl-Alt-F3 Ctrl-Alt-F4 Ctrl-Alt-F5 and Ctrl-Alt-F6 then click on [edit] and report your findings. Please do not use Add Comment; instead, please use [edit].

Comment: Maybe it's possible to install the packages from a live usb, chrooting your hard disk system.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to start Ubuntu in Console mode](https://askubuntu.com/questions/859630/how-to-start-ubuntu-in-console-mode) and [Removed Python 3 and now Ubuntu Software Center, terminal and other applications don't work](https://askubuntu.com/q/384033/)

Answer (score 0):

If friendlier options fail, you can try:

1. Boot a live USB.
2. Open a terminal and mount the partition where ubuntu lives:

   ```
   sudo mount /dev/sdX /mnt
   ```
3. Chroot to your system:

   ```
   sudo chroot /mnt
   ```
4. Now in the root environment it's possible you have to edit `/etc/resolv.conf`:

   ```
   nano /etc/resolv.conf
   ```

   add

   ```
   nameserver 8.8.8.8
   ```

   and save the file
5. Run `sudo apt update`
6. Run sudo `apt install python3`
7. Close your live system and reboot.