# problem in sudo apt-get install --reinstall ubuntu-desktop

Tags: package-management, upgrade, dpkg, reinstall

There are some problems with my Ubuntu 18.04 packages. I want to reinstall my Ubuntu via terminal, but when I type :

```
 sudo apt-get install --reinstall ubuntu-desktop
```

It shows :

```
Reading package lists... Done
Building dependency tree       
Reading state information... Done
Reinstallation of ubuntu-desktop is not possible, it cannot be downloaded.
0 upgraded, 0 newly installed, 0 to remove and 0 not upgraded
```

Is there any way to reinstall my Ubuntu? I have taken my file backup.
Thank you.

Comment: Did you forget to run `sudo apt-get update` first?

Comment: [Edit]ing your question to add the output of `apt policy ubuntu-desktop` would be helpful.

Answer (score 1):

I haven't tried it myself but I presume the system won't reinstall the desktop while it is in use. Instead of logging into the desktop and opening a terminal, log into console mode:

- [How to start Ubuntu in Console mode](https://askubuntu.com/questions/859630/how-to-start-ubuntu-in-console-mode/859637#859637)

Before changing make sure you note the settings for:

```
GRUB_CMDLINE_LINUX_DEFAULT="quiet splash"
#GRUB_TERMINAL=console
```

After rebooting and logging into console use:

```
sudo apt update
sudo apt install --reinstall ubuntu-desktop
sudo apt install --reinstall unity
```

The last command is only necessary if you are using the Unity interface.

Now reverse the changes for console mode and reboot.

Answer (score 0):

Try:

> - sudo dpkg —configure -a
> - sudo apt update
> - sudo apt -f install
> - sudo apt full-upgrade
> - sudo apt install —reinstall ubuntu desktop
> - sudo apt autoremove
> - sudo apt clean
> - sudo reboot

Alternatively you can use:

> dconf reset -f /

**Careful since this reset whole system. w**