# Cannot install Ubuntu Desktop on Ubuntu 20.04.2 LTS

Tags: apt, gnome

My PC series is Lenovo V110-14AST.
I cannot install Ubuntu Desktop now. Once I log in to system, it is in tty mode.
I used the command:

```
sudo apt-get update
sudo apt-get upgrade
sudo apt-get install gdm3 gnome-shell ubuntu-desktop ubuntu-gnome-desktop
```

But it said: `Package ubuntu-desktop is not available, but is referred to by another package.`

Comment: (1) Putting it into Google Translate gives this: "There is no available package ubuntu-desktop, but it is referenced by other packages. ". (2) If you are trying to convert Ubuntu Server into Ubuntu Desktop, I suggest following [these directions](https://askubuntu.com/q/322122/1438484) instead of trying to do it yourself

Comment: If you need to reinstall the desktop, [this answer](https://askubuntu.com/a/1207583/1222991) may help 