# Input signal out of range Change settings to 1600x900 60

Tags: 18.04, graphics, display-resolution, input, signal

Ubuntu was working fine till i changed the resolution to one that was higher than the recommended settings(1600x900) now i don't know what to do. Any help?

Comment: No it doesn't, cause the whole screen is black and says input signal out of range change resolution.......
i'm currently using recovery mode

Comment: [Become root in recovery mode](https://askubuntu.com/a/859640/)

Comment: @karel I tried it out but still doesn't fix it but i found a solution.

Answer (score 0):

After hearing the login sound type in your password.(if required; since you can't see)
then open the Terminal
ctrl+alt+T
Type in
`sudo xrandr -s 1600x900`
type in admin password and hit enter.
The display should return