# How to switch the display manager to tbsm?

Tags: 20.04, display-manager

How to switch the display manager to tbsm?

I just installed tbsm display manager from their source, but I don't know how to switch to it, I know I can go to lightdm with `dpkg-reconfigure lightdm` but I couldn't figure it out how to switch to tbsm

Comment: You have to read their manual https://github.com/loh-tar/tbsm/blob/master/doc/01_Manual.txt .Starting `tbsm` is possible from text ttys like <Ctrl><Alt><F1>.

Comment: You can pick your display manager at the login screen. There isn't a need to run a console and then the `tbsm` menu to pick a display manager.

Comment: @WinEunuuchs2Unix I actually meant login manager, the place you enter your password and also your desktop env, did I misunderstand the word "display manager"?

Comment: @TheDark_Command Sorry I misunderstood your intentions. I think you want to start Ubuntu in console mode and have `tbsm` auto-start? https://askubuntu.com/questions/859630/how-to-start-ubuntu-in-console-mode/859637#859637