# Ubuntu 22.10 doesn't boot since kernel update

Tags: boot, nvidia, kernel, updates

At startup, the console briefly shows the message "nvidia-gpu i2c timeout error". Then systemd hangs at the message "Started GNOME Display manager ... with any system changes".

This is probably due to the kernel update. I'm using nvidia GPU drivers.

I don't know how to boot into a console to reinstall my drivers. The shortcut `Ctrl` + `Alt` + `F1` doesn't work. Rescue mode doesn't work ("get root console" option just makes the computer freeze).

Is it acceptable for a modern distro to break from a kernel update ? This issue has been known for at least 17 years, (although the solution to the original question doesn't work anymore).

I have a BIOS motherboard (no UEFI).

Thanks.

Comment: The only question in this post is "Is it acceptable for a modern distro to break from a kernel update ? " which is opinion-based.

Comment: You should have at least two possible "Recovery console"entries in the grub menu; one using the previous kernel (which I'd expect to work), and one for the just installed kernel (which I assume is the one not working - uninstall, then reinstall?). Tell more details! Also note: If the storage used for the kernels ( `/boot` ? ) is full, you will have a nonworking, halfway-installed kernel, clean it out!)

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How to start Ubuntu in Console mode](https://askubuntu.com/questions/859630/how-to-start-ubuntu-in-console-mode)