# How can I switch between starting and stopping a desktop process without rebooting the OS

Tags: lubuntu, desktop-environments

I installed lubuntu-desktop.

I usually only use CUI.

But sometimes I want to use GUI.

I want the desktop process to start only then.

Normally, desktop process should be stopped.

How can I switch between starting and stopping a desktop process without rebooting the OS.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How to start Ubuntu in Console mode](https://askubuntu.com/questions/859630/how-to-start-ubuntu-in-console-mode)

Comment: `sudo systemctl isolate multi-user.target` former text-mode without desktop session. To switch back `sudo systtemctl isolate default.target` or `systemctl isolate graphical.target`

Comment: You've not provided release details so adjust the answers for your *unstated* Ubuntu product.  I've in the past set it up for *runlevel*; system booted to 3 for terminal & I just increased that to 5 for desktop (or returned to 3 & GUI was killed); but what @nobody suggests could be used too.

Comment: Hi, @nobody. Your answer is exactly what I was looking for.  As expected, GUI processes can now disappear and reappear.  thank you.