# Change windows manager from recovery mode?

Tags: window-manager, recovery-mode

Is this possible?

`choosewm` says its not installed and I can't install it, presumably because I can't connect to WiFi from recovery mode

I'm running Fossa

Comment: Do you mean `choosewm` ?  Recovery mode is used to *fix* issues and may involve runlevels being used that have networking disabled; you've not provided your product & release details so we'd mostly be guessing currently anyway.

Comment: K I've edited. Fossa. Yes I'm trying to fix an issue and recover the use of my computer.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How to start Ubuntu in Console mode](https://askubuntu.com/q/859630/)