# HP Pavilion Ubuntu installation BIOS problem

Tags: boot, drivers, bios, bootloader, firmware

I'm trying to install Ubuntu LTS on my new HP Pavilion laptop and getting these errors:

[image]

Detailed explanation:

I'm trying to install Ubuntu on my newly purchased HP Pavilion which came out of the box with Windows OS.

To create a bootable USB, I used Ventoy.

After booting with USB and Selecting Ubuntu OS, the Ubuntu Grub bootloader shows up after selecting the "Try or install Ubuntu" this error pops up.

I thought this error might be just within the installation process, but after installation this error occurs on every boot.

I also faced two other issues.

1. While installing Ubuntu I connected my machine to my home wifi and it was working fine, but after installation and restarting the machine whenever I tried to connect to my home wifi, I got an error "Activation network connection failed" error.
2. Even After formatting the disk using Ubuntu's GParted software and selecting the *Erase the disk and install Ubuntu* option during the installation process, the Windows Boot Manager was still present in the BIOS boot menu options. It was not getting removed from the BIOS Boot Option, and the weird thing was that Grub Customizer was not showing it.

I have installed Ubuntu on more than three machines and never faced any of these issues, but I don't know why I'm getting these errors this time.

After facing these issues I thought there might be something wrong with my BIOS/firmware so I reinstalled Windows OS. I ran HP support assistance and hardware diagnostics and got no errors or updates from that software.

Comment: I often see various such errors shown during boot up on a perfectly functioning box so I would say you can ignore these ... if you have a boot up issue look elsewhere ... if your box fails to boot up then boot it up in  "Recovery Mode" then get into root prompt to be able to issue terminal commands   ... see  https://askubuntu.com/a/859640/18025

Comment: update your question to state whether your errors happen when you are trying to boot up from your LiveUSB memory stick before you do this OS install onto your box or after you have installed the new OS and are then getting errors during the freshly installed OS boot up

Comment: I have updated the question with details, can you please help me?

Comment: These `AE_ALREADY_EXISTS` messages are probably harmless. You only feel safer with Windows, because Windows suppresses all of these problems. I'm no expert in ACPI messages, but my wild guess is that some USB devices are attempted to be registered twice (So they are already registered and there is probably no problem). 

Do you have any USB problems? Because XHCI refers to a USB controller.

Answer (score -1):

It seems like your laptop (like most of other new HP laptops) is designed to be compatible with Microsoft Windows. That's why you are seeing windows boot manager in boot options even though you have removed the partition. The errors that you see while booting are usually due to conflicts between the kernel and your motherboard (usually chipset).
And about wifi; there must something wrong with your wifi driver. You can try the driver from HP support website (if any exists for linux).
Another possibility is your installation media is faulty.