# Can´t start terminal in any way, or TTY, after installing Python 3.12 on Ubuntu 20.04

Tags: gnome-terminal, python3, tty

After installing Python 3.12 on Ubuntu 20.04 I cant start the Terminal in any way, nor can I start TTY to solve the problem. Any ideas?

Comment: You can install other python3 versions, but if you change the default version you'll find many of the Desktop tools like no longer work (*those that rely on python3*).  Reverse your changes (restore backups etc); as non-working tools are the best outcome, as corruption by badly-working tools is the worse outcome (*this is rare but may not be noticed until too late; do not change the default python3 version on desktop systems*)

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How to start Ubuntu in Console mode](https://askubuntu.com/questions/859630/how-to-start-ubuntu-in-console-mode) and [Removed Python 3 and now Ubuntu Software Center, terminal and other applications don't work](https://askubuntu.com/q/384033/)